# Web Performance Testing context paramters

Tags: asp.net, web, performance-testing

I used the MSDN [guide on creating Custom Extraction Rule](http://www.google.com/), which presents this example (`Extract` method):

```
    public override void Extract(object sender, ExtractionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Response.HtmlDocument != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlTag tag in e.Response.HtmlDocument.GetFilteredHtmlTags(new string[] { "input" }))
            {
                if (String.Equals(tag.GetAttributeValueAsString("name"), Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    string formFieldValue = tag.GetAttributeValueAsString("value");
                    if (formFieldValue == null)
                    {
                        formFieldValue = String.Empty;
                    }

                    // add the extracted value to the web performance test context
                    e.WebTest.Context.Add("someNameHere", formFieldValue);
                    e.Success = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        // If the extraction fails, set the error text that the user sees
        e.Success = false;
        e.Message = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Not Found: {0}", Name);
    }
```

However, I just don't know how to use access the `someNameHere` in the Web Test and add it to the QueryString as a parameter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the request in the web test and select "Add URL query string parameter". Alter the name as needed and into the value field enter `{{someNameHere}}`. The doubled curly braces call for a context parameter value to be inserted. The doubled curly braces can be used to insert the value of a context parameter into many other places in a web test. Note that strings such as `text{{someNameHere}}moretext` can be used to join context values to other strings.