# How to extract the X-XSRF_TOKEN in a web performance test

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing, web-performance

I had written a web performance test which was earlier working fine. Developers now have added a CSRF token validation (to prevent CSRF attack on the website). After this the test has started to fail (Error, Bad Request). I dug into it and found that the server is generating an XSRF-TOKEN on login request which has to be passed in every request there after. 
Now to extract the token we need to parse response to the login request. How can we do it?

My coded tests looks like this:

```
WebTestRequest request4 = new WebTestRequest("https://servertest:8080/WebConsole/Account/Login");
request4.Method = "POST";
request4.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"));
request4.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Referer", "https://servertest:8080/WebConsole/index.html#/"));
StringHttpBody request4Body = new StringHttpBody();
request4Body.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
request4Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
request4Body.BodyString = "{\"UserName\":\"pkdomain\\\\administrator\",\"Password\":\"sqa@123\"}";
request4.Body = request4Body;
yield return request4;
request4 = null;

WebTestRequest request5 = new WebTestRequest("https://servertest:8080/WebConsole/scripts/home/Pages/home-view.html");
request5.ThinkTime = 4;
request5.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html"));
request5.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Referer", "https://servertest:8080/WebConsole/index.html#/"));
yield return request5;
request5 = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `XSRF-TOKEN` is returned in a cookie. Assuming that this is true in your case then the `Set-Cookie` header field contains the value and the required cookie must be extracted from it and saved to a context parameter. Subsequently that context parameter can be used wherever needed.

I suggest you create a sandbox `.webtest` file, do the steps below then convert it to coded test and copy the useful lines into the real test.

In more detail the steps are:

Add an `Extract HTTP Header` extraction rule for the `Set-Cookie` header field to the request that returns the `XSRF-TOKEN` value. Save the extracted value to a context parameter of your choice, give its name in one of the properties of the extraction rule; see the image below.

Add a call of the plugin below to the first request after the one with the above extraction rule. It extracts the required field from the cookie header field. The image below shows setting the properties of the call. (You might change the plugin to be a `PostRequest` and add it to the same request as the one with the extraction rule.)

```
public class ExtractCookieField : WebTestRequestPlugin
{
    public string AllCookiesCP { get; set; }

    public string FieldWantedCP { get; set; }

    public string SavedFieldCP { get; set; }

    // Expected to be called with AllCookiesCP containing text similar to:
    //     SomeHeader=639025785406236250; path=/; XSRF-TOKEN=somestring; secure; HttpOnly

    public override void PreRequestDataBinding(object sender, PreRequestDataBindingEventArgs e)
    {
        string AllCookiesText = e.WebTest.Context[AllCookiesCP].ToString();

        foreach (string nameValuePair in AllCookiesText.Split(';'))
        {
            string[] nameAndValue = nameValuePair.Split(new char[] { '=' }, 2);

            if (nameAndValue[0].Trim() == FieldWantedCP)
            {
                string sessionTokenId = nameAndValue[1].Trim();
                e.WebTest.Context[SavedFieldCP] = sessionTokenId;
                e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult(string.Format("Setting {{{0}}} to '{1}'", SavedFieldCP, sessionTokenId));
                return;
            }
        }

        // Dropping out of the loop means that the field was not found.
        throw new WebTestException(string.Format("Cannot extract cookie field '{0}' from '{1}'", FieldWantedCP, AllCookiesText));
    }
}
```

The value of the `XSRF-TOKEN` should now be in the context parameter specified in the `SavedFieldCP` property of the plugin call.

This image shows the add extraction rule dialogue and setting the context parameter where the extracted header field is saved, ie into `CookieValues`. It also show the add plugin and setting the three properties. After the plugin runs, assuming it is successful, the token value should be saved into the context parameter `XsrfToken`. The parameter values can be modified in the `.webtest` file via the properties panels of the extraction rule and the plugin. The values should also be clearly seen as simple variables and strings in a coded webb test.

[image: Properties panels for extraction rule and plugins]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have made the suggseted change but I am not sure what do you mean by "Save the extracted value to a context parameter".

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried adding another Extraction rule but I got an error saying "The extraction rule ExtractHiddenFields can only be applied to a response that is either an HTML document or a partial rendering response."                                                                                                    We are making a lot of AJAX calls. Could that be the reason for the failure. Apologies, I am very new to Web Performance Tests

Comment: @user2606622 That is a different question and may be best asked as a new question. To answer it we would need to see the response headers. That message is probably not Ajax related, it is more likely that you are trying to extract hidden fields from a picture file (eg a `.jpg` or `.gif` etc).

Comment: @user2606622 My apologies, I must have confused you by circling the wrong extraction rule in the image. I have modified the image to circle the correct rule.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I have been able to partially get this working. I am now able to extract 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' from AllCookiesCP. But this token is not passed to the subsequent request headers. I think e.WebTest.Context[SavedFieldCP] = sessionTokenId;                                 needs to be changed. Could you please help me out here?

Comment: The statement `e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult...` causes the saved value to be seen in the log of the test run. Does it show the expected value? Also, look in the "context" tab of the log for requests after the plugin is used, does it show the expected values? To use the value in subsequent requests you have to explicitly add it. The value will not be done automagically.

Comment: Yes, the log shows the expected value. (Setting X-XSRF-TOKEN to '2b0913db-d265-e4bb-7f7c-a7bf6fc5b1cc').                                           The context tab also shows the expected value                                    X-XSRF-TOKEN 2b0913db-d265-e4bb-7f7c-a7bf6fc5b1cc       But the request fails nevertheless (saying, Bad Request). Also, I do not see the sessionID in the request header.

Comment: This is how the code generated for the request looks like                        ExtractCookieField requestPlugin1 = new ExtractCookieField();  requestPlugin1.AllCookiesCP = "CookieValues";
requestPlugin1.FieldWantedCP = "secure,XSRF-TOKEN";
requestPlugin1.SavedFieldCP = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
request5.PreRequestDataBinding += new EventHandler<PreRequestDataBindingEventArgs>(requestPlugin1.PreRequestDataBinding);
request5.PreRequest += new EventHandler<PreRequestEventArgs>(requestPlugin1.PreRequest);
 request5.PostRequest += new EventHandler<PostRequestEventArgs>(requestPlugin1.PostRequest);

Comment: I think you need to add the value as a header fields to the subsequent requests. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20433736/546871 , it is about query strings but the method is the same for headers.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Earlier I was able to extract the XSRF-TOKEN but I was not able to pass it as an header. I right clicked the failing request and used "Add Header" option to add XSRF-TOKEN in request headers and then it worked :).

Comment: I was able to get the web test working. But when I generated coded web test and tried to run it fails saying, "There is no context parameter with the name 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' in the WebTestContext". I need to get the coded test because I want to parametrize the web test. I have no clue why it is failing, when the coded test is derived from the same web test. Could you please throw some light here.

Comment: What does the `AddCommentToResult` display and what context parameters are available? Are you adding the header to the correct request? Are you trying to add the header to the request that returns the value, ie to use it before it is available? What does *"I need to get the coded test because I want to parametrize the web test"* mean? What parameters can you not set in a `.webtest` file? Perhaps you need to start a new question on how to use context parameters in a web test.

Comment: AddCommentToResult prints correct XSRF-TOKEN when run via the webtest. But an exception is thrown when run via CODED test. I think I have added headers to correct request (since the webtest runs fine, this should be a valid assumption). I am using the coded test to parameterize  login credentials, and other inputs.

Comment: Lets us continue this in chat. See http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/123265/how-to-extract-the-x-xsrf-token-in-a-web-performance-test?tab=general