# How to bind user defined extraction rule dynamically in WebTest?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, webtest

Apart from "Promote Dynamic parameter to webtest parameter"(which binds session key only),
Can we able to bind fetchgriddata=>grid name,execute grid action,etc? for which extraction rules are user defined.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  I think that one of these answers covers what you want. If not then please clarify your question. The idea is rather than using a "bind" command, just enter the context parameter name enclosed in doubled curly braces into the field. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430335/web-performance-testing-context-paramters/20433736#20433736 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673194/546871 .

Comment: When clicking "Promote dynamic parameter to webtest parameter" menu it will add extraction rule to the parent request and bind the extraction rule to the value of the session key of many child request,ryt??..Are you getting this?

Comment: I understand the "promote dynamic ..." text. But what is your question? Please [edit] the question to explain in detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please Let me complete. I have added some extraction rule(user defined extraction rule)..That will not get bind to the parent request when clicking "Promote dynamic parameter to webtest parameter".Ryt?

Comment: Has your question been answered? If not then please add extra details as has been requested. As the moment there is not enough detail to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after a test is recorded, Visual Studio asks whether it should *"Promote dynamic parameters to webtest parameters"*. If you are not sure then answering "Yes" is normally best. After recording and promoting dynamic parameters the test can be further customized (i.e. made to work). One of the tools is the use of *extraction rules* and then using the extracted values in later parts of the test.

The way that promoting dynamic parameters to webtest parameters works is by creating extraction rules and inserting the values where needed. This automated detection of dynamic data finds many things but it does not (and I think it can not) find all dynamic data items. Hence the test author often needs to find other dynamic data items.

Back on the details of the question. You cannot add extraction rules to a web test before *"Promote dynamic parameters to webtest parameters"* is asked. Hence  the values in your extraction rules cannot be automatically bound into the test.

See also [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d30d48b9-1552-47b2-9ddc-31610cbb00ab/what-does-promote-dynamic-parameter-to-webtest-parameter-do?forum=vstswebtest) which has some more details.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any idea to link user defined extraction rule to the child request(as of now we have to bind manually to the child requests)?

Comment: @Kiruthik I have tried to help you on two very poorly written questions. On both I have asked you to explain your question in more detail. You have added a few words to them but not explained things properly. Please read the [help] pages on how to write a good question. If you have a problem then YOU need to put some effort into explaining that problem so that other people can help YOU. If you fail to write a clear and understandable question then you will not get any useful answers; and, you waste your time and that of everyone else who looks at the question.